# oracle sql - on delete cascade in both directions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table A and table B, where the primary key of table B references the primary key of table A. If i use *on delete cascade* on table B how can i ensure that rows of table A are deleted when i delete a row in table B?

Edit:
Merging is unfortunately not the solution to my problem.
In my database i have three tables that are relevant for this situation.
This is what it looks like:

```
    CREATE TABLE TABLE_A
    (
    TABLE_A_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(TABLE_A_ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE TABLE_B
    (
    TABLE_B_ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_A(TABLE_A_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(TABLE_B_ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE TABLE_C
    (
    TABLE_C_ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_A(TABLE_A_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(TABLE_C_ID)
    );
```

Although it is possible to create rows in A on its own i dont want any rows that are only in A.

Now if I delete a row in B, I want the row in A with the same ID deleted too. I dont want any ID that is only in A, or only not in A.

Comment: you don't need 2 primary key referencing  each other, just use one primary key (main table) and one foreign key

Comment: If your primary key on table B is also a foreign key pointing to table A, then you should merge the 2 tables.

Comment: As the only user whose username does not begin with `user`, I'd like to chime in a say that if you really have this need, it might indicate a problem with your database design.  Maybe add more information to your question.